# Python Programming - Finding Invalid records from the excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

We have an excel sheet which contain 24 columns and 4 columns are Primary columns.

1. Whenever any of the primary columns doesn't contain values (i.e Null or Blank) that record should be "Invalid Record"
2. Whenever any of the primary columns contain values that record should be "Valid Record"

How do I find those "Invalid Records" and generate an excel workbook by using python?

Need Help on this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xlsxwriter` for this.

I followed this [tutorial](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html) to create the file `test.xlsx` and append a new column to it. For your file, you'll have to load the `xlsx` file and append a 25th column to it.

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

data = (
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], # column names
    ['', '-', '', ''],    # valid
    ['', '', '-', ''],    # valid
    ['-', '', '', '-'],   # valid
    ['', '', '', ''],     # invalid
    ['', '', '-', ''],    # valid
    ['-', '', '', '-'],   # valid
    ['', '', '', ''],     # invalid
)

row = 0
col = 0

for a, b, c, d in data:
    worksheet.write(row, col, a)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 1, b)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 2, c)
    worksheet.write(row, col + 3, d)
    if (a or b or c or d):
        worksheet.write(row, col + 4, 'Valid Record')
    else:
        worksheet.write(row, col + 4, 'Invalid Record')
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```